# How to return the number of documents changed in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I am querying for documents using AngularFire and I am trying to return the number of documents changed using onSnapshot().

```
get_docChange_count(uid : string) : number  {
      return this.afs.collection('events').ref.where('uid', '==', uid).onSnapshot(res => {
            return res.docChanges().length;
       });
  }
```

But this gives following error in my VS code editor :

> Type '() => void' is not assignable to type 'number'

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Seems like you want to use `get()` for a one-time query instead of `onSnapshot()`, which establishes an ongoing listener.

Comment: Since documents in DB tends to change frequently and I need to capture the count of changed documents as soon as documents change in DB. Since ,```get()``` does not attach any listener therefore ```onSnapshot()``` seems to provide the expected behavior.

Comment: Then you will not be able to have the function just return a number when it's called. The caller will have to specify a callback function to receive the results as they change.

Comment: @DougStevenson How can I achieve this using callback function? please consider helping me with code implementation.